# How to install Librewolf/Waterfox in Raspberry Pi OS?

Tags: software-installation

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I'm linux newbie and don't know how to install/compile Librewolf and Waterfox for latest Raspberry Pi OS.

> Librewolf: This is for Debian Unstable only - do not try to install this package on any other branch of Debian or Ubuntu/Mint, or you will have errors about being unable to resolve the dependencies.

I think Waterfox should be compiled first.

[Librefox Install](https://librewolf-community.gitlab.io/install/)

[Waterfox Download](https://www.waterfox.net/download/)

[Waterfox GitHub](https://github.com/MrAlex94/Waterfox)

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded LibreWolf AppImage from GitLab and it seems to run fine on Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS 64bit "bullseye" Desktop. Just make sure to download the **aarch64** AppImage and make the downloaded file executable by **chmod +x** before starting it.